# How can I get the min value of the first row in a 2d array and then print

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, 2d

I want to print the min value of the first row of a 2d array that has only 5 elements in row and column:

```
for(int row=0;row<table.length;row++){


           for(int column=0;column<table[0].length;column++){

               if(table[row][column]<table[row][min]){
                   min=row;
               }
               result{row]=table[row][min];
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are assigning the value of the incrementing variable `row` to `min` instead of the array value `table[column][row]`. I'm also unsure why you are looping through both the rows and the columns if you only want the first row, so you'll probably want to change this too. From what I can tell from your description, it also seems you really want to assign `table[0][row]`...

So you'll likely want to change:

`table[row][column]<table[row][min]`

to

`table[0][column]<table[row][min]`

and

`min = row` to

`table[0][row]`

I haven't tested this but it seems like this should fix your problems (you don't say what output you're getting at the moment...). Let me know if you are still having problems after that and what the output of the code is.